# The difference between lun and volume in qnap nas

Tags: snapshot, nas, volumes, qnap

I have 2 qnap Nas.first Nas have 4 hard with 10 TB volume, and second Nas have 4 hard with 14 TB volume.

I want to use from these Nases to save snapshot and data log from my 10 virtual servers that are in 4 physical servers.

I use raid 5 in each Nas.

I don't know what is the best configuration for this Nases to this job.

For example, what is difference between  lun and volume in Nas?

And which one is good to use for this work?

Both Nas will work and take backup and snapshot independently from other.

Can you help me ,to say which one is good to used for creat partition for each physical server in Nas, volume or lun?

And other configuration that is needed.

Now I create new volume in Nas.
And divide space for each volume.
Is necessary to use from nas snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a QNAP NAS (Network Attached Storage), "LUN" and "volume" refer to different concepts related to storage management.

LUN (Logical Unit Number):

A LUN is a logical representation of a storage device or subsystem on a SAN (Storage Area Network).
It is typically used in block-level storage protocols such as iSCSI (Internet Small Computer System Interface) or Fibre Channel.
LUNs are often presented to servers or clients as if they were physical disks.
LUNs can be part of a RAID group, and they are often used to provide block-level access to storage for applications or virtual machines.
Volume:

In the context of QNAP NAS, a volume is a storage pool created using the NAS operating system (e.g., QTS).
A volume can be created using different RAID configurations, combining multiple physical hard drives into a single storage entity.
Volumes are typically used with file-level protocols such as SMB (Server Message Block) or NFS (Network File System).
QNAP NAS supports various RAID levels, such as RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, RAID 6, and RAID 10, which can be used to configure volumes with different levels of data protection and performance.
Key Differences:

Abstraction Level:

LUN operates at the block level, presenting storage to servers or clients as block devices.
Volume operates at a higher level, providing file-level storage that can be accessed by networked devices.
Protocols:

LUN is often associated with block-level protocols like iSCSI or Fibre Channel.
Volume is associated with file-level protocols like SMB or NFS.
Use Cases:

LUNs are typically used for applications or environments that require block-level access, such as databases or virtualization.
Volumes are more commonly used for general file storage, sharing files over a network, and running applications that work at the file level.
In summary, while both LUNs and volumes are storage concepts, they operate at different levels of abstraction and are associated with different storage protocols. LUNs are more geared toward block-level access, often used in SAN environments, while volumes in QNAP NAS are designed for file-level access and are created using the NAS operating system's storage management features.